# android: one button, 2 string resources

Tags: android

I've a question about **how i can handle 2 different language string resources like .e.g 
@string/buttontext_de and @string/buttontext_en related to ONE menu button?**

I've one start button and i want to display **the right string resource which user device language is set.**

1) I've 2 directories, one "res\values" (its the default german values directory) and one "res\values-en" where i've put in the english text resource (in strings.xml)

2) Next step i've to set the localization code in my start activity?

3) How can i set code that my button text is choosing the right language string resource?

THX a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) Developer Guide.  Just specify duplicate String resources in the appropriate folders, step back, and let the I18N magic happen.  To test it, go into your Settings (Einstellungen) and change your system language preference.

Thanks to Bytebender for pointing out what I missed.  Yes, you want to create these files and resources:

Inside `res/values-en/strings.xml`:

```
<string name="buttontext">Click Me</string>
```

Inside `res/values-de/strings.xml`:

```
<string name="buttontext">Hier Klicken</string>
```

Then refer to it in your XML like this:

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/myBtnId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="doHandleBtnClick"
    android:text="@string/buttontext" />
```

Comment: In other words `@string/buttontext_de` and `@string/buttontext_en` should both just be `@string/buttontext`...

Comment: ok, thx! but how is it possible to define 2 words into @string/buttontext? with a comma? e.g.

Comment: great! thx a lot, i think i can get this! and in my start activity..is it enough to define

Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();

or do i need another code to complete user device language?

Comment: You don't need to do that.  Just specify your resources in XML, and the OS takes care of the details.  It's kind of magic, just like how it can change your layout when you rotate the device.

Comment: The only messy thing is that i've now in the graphical layout as text "@string/buttontext" So eclipse can't resolve it..how can I solve this? i can't check my other layout components now...

Comment: Um... take the locale off one of your resource folders so it's just plain res/values, I suppose.

Comment: I dind't find any settings to configure this :(